How to derive the sampling distribution of method of moment estimators for uniform distribution
Let $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ be a random sample from $Unif[a,b]$.
By simple calculation, the method of moment estimator for $(a,b)$ is
$(\hat{a},\hat{b})=$
$$(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sqrt{3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - 3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \sqrt{3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - 3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2})$$.
We may use the delta method to derive the asymptotic distribution for $(\hat{a},\hat{b})$. However, I have no idea whether the exact sampling distribution of this estimator exists and how to derive it.
I appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Well I am not so sure about your simple calculations ... how is $(E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sqrt{3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - 3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2}],E[ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \sqrt{3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2) - 3(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2}])=(a,b)$ exactly ?

@TheBridge There is no expectation since it's a method of moment estimator. Here is the discussion about these calculations.

@TheBridge I believe the estimators $\  \hat{a},\hat{b}\ $ are biassed, so it's not true that $\ E(\hat{a})=a\ $ or $\ E(\hat{b})=b\ $.  Nevertheless, $$\ E\left(3\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2\right)\right)=\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2\ ,$$
so, for sufficiently large $\ n\ $ you can expect the bias to be small, and $\  \hat{a},\hat{b}\ $ ought to be reasonable estimators for $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ .$

@TheBridge Thanks for your explanation, but I'm struggling to derive the estimators' sampling distributions. Do you have any suggestions for the derivation?
